# Display a collection of custom Dexterity content types with specific headers

Tags: plone, dexterity, plone-4.x

Dexterity questions all day, today!

So the next thing we're trying to do with these custom Dexterity "files" is to have collections of them throughout the website display in a table with certain headers. Is this possible? Currently the tabular_view that comes default with collections only shows these options:

[image: Table columns default options]

So it ends up looking like:

[image: A collection of Dexterity "Files"]

However, we want the table headers to be: Title, Type, Program, and Year, based on the fields in the Dexterity content type settings:

[image: The main "tag" fields]

Is this even possible? The reason we're using collections is because we want to show a subsection of these files within different areas of the website. Possibly also, we want to use collection portlets to display like, the three most recent files, on other pages.

Would we be better off using multiple instances of eea.facetednav everywhere?

Comment: Possible columns on the collection tabular view are taken from metadata index.

You must first add those additional fields to `portal_catalog` metadata. See http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/searching_and_indexing/indexing.html

Then you must configure collections to see it in collections. See how plone.app.querystring is doing: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.querystring/blob/master/plone/app/querystring/profiles/default/registry.xml

Comment: Thanks Keul! I was able to add them to the metadata index, but I'm not quite sure what you mean by configuring the collections — do I need to edit the collection template in the ZMI or somewhere on the filesystem?

Comment: I suspect what keul ment, is to go to the controlpanel->collections, click on "show all fields" and select the fieldnames you want to have selectable in collections. For programatically reproducing, export the refering xml-file via GenericSetup.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the code of [collective.nitf](https://github.com/collective/collective.nitf/blob/master/src/collective/nitf/profiles/default/registry.xml) as we do what @keul is recommending at package installation.

specifically, you will need something like this for every field you want to add:

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <registry xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
    i18n:domain="plone">

    <records condition="installed plone.app.collection"
        interface="plone.app.querystring.interfaces.IQueryField"
        prefix="plone.app.querystring.field.genre">
      <value key="title" i18n:translate="">Genre</value>
      <value key="description" i18n:translate="">An NITF genre field</value>
      <value key="enabled">True</value>
      <value key="sortable">True</value>
      <value key="operations">
        <element>plone.app.querystring.operation.selection.is</element>
      </value>
      <value key="vocabulary">collective.nitf.AvailableGenres</value>
      <value key="group" i18n:translate="">NITF</value>
    </records>
  </registry>
```